# SQL-Server - Help to find Responses with 11

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a question on an SQL.

I have a table which contains, Question Responses from different customers.

Following Basic Code:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, QUESTIONS_ID, RESPONSE, CALENDAR_MONTH FROM
DB.[dbo].[T_FCT_QUESTIONS]
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH = '201607'
AND RESPONSE = '11'
```

What i need to find out ist, the Question_ID's of Customers which contain the response 11 and if there is only a 11 as response or are there also other results from (0-10) in a particular calendar month.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT QUESTIONS_ID, 
       (CASE WHEN MAX(RESPONSE) = '11' AND MIN(RESPONSE) = '11'
             THEN 'ONLY 11'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN RESPONSE = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'SOME 11'
             ELSE 'NO 11'
        END) as INFO_11
FROM DB.[dbo].[T_FCT_QUESTIONS]
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH = '201607'
GROUP BY QUESTIONS_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood, I propose this solution.
You should do two `SELECT` statements with grouping, one for RESPONSE 11 and the other for other RESPONSE codes. Then you have to join these selections with a LEFT JOIN.

```
  SELECT
  Resp11.*,
  CASE
   WHEN Resp0_10.CALENDAR_MONTH IS NULL AND Resp0_10.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL AND Resp0_10.QUESTIONS_ID IS NULL
    THEN 'No other RESPONSE for this month'
   ELSE 'Other RESPONSE for this month'
  END
FROM
(
SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, QUESTIONS_ID
 FROM DB.[dbo].[T_FCT_QUESTIONS]
 WHERE RESPONSE = '11'
 GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, QUESTIONS_ID
) Resp11
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, QUESTIONS_ID
 FROM DB.[dbo].[T_FCT_QUESTIONS]
 WHERE RESPONSE >= '0' AND  RESPONSE <= '10'
 GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, QUESTIONS_ID
) Resp0_10
 ON Resp11.CALENDAR_MONTH=Resp0_10.CALENDAR_MONTH
  AND Resp11.CUSTOMER_ID=Resp0_10.CUSTOMER_ID
  AND Resp11.QUESTIONS_ID=Resp0_10.QUESTIONS_ID
```

Items not available in the second selections wll have only NULL items, so no other response is given for these items.

Comment: Hello Lucbert, this Solution works fine, and gives me the needed result, thank you very much for this fast and nice solution to find these results.! THX and BR Rudi

Answer (score 0):

You can select the Customers which have a response `11` and all their questions and responses with the following:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, QUESTIONS_ID, RESPONSE, CALENDAR_MONTH
FROM DB.[dbo].[T_FCT_QUESTIONS] a
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM DB.[dbo].[T_FCT_QUESTIONS] b
   WHERE RESPONSE = '11'
     AND b.CUSTOMER_ID = a.CUSTOMER_ID
     AND b.QUESTIONS_ID = a.QUESTIONS_ID
     AND b.CALENDAR_MONTH = a.CALENDAR_MONTH
     AND b.CALENDAR_MONTH = '201607' --This could also be a parameter?
  )
```

Comment: Hi NickyvV, thx for your help, this only gives me all with 11 but i need to know which contain only 11 and which contain 11 and something else. THX and BR Rudi